# Lunch menu, SQL weekly

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to store weekly lunch menus. A lunch menu will last the week and then there will be a new lunch menu for the next.

Here's what I got so far:

```
Menu

id
from


Dishes

id
menu_id
day (1 - 7) 1 Monday, 7 Sunday
name
price
```

But I'm not sure how I should store the date and how to retrieve each week based on NOW(). from is a DateTime, and let's say  I want to grab the two weeks coming lunch menus, how can I do that?

My idea is something like this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE from BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

doesn't work that well though.

How should I keep track of the dates and how can I retrieve the 2 lunch menus on this week and the next one?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: homework???  show some effort dude.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL.

Comment: @TMcKeown nope im too old for homework :-)

Comment: you should store an effectiveStartDate and a effectiveEndDate for the dates.

Comment: I'd probably go with a weeknumber over dates.

Answer (score 0):

"from" is a reserved word in mysql so its a bad idea to name one of your columns after it.